# Get name of area in controller

Tags: asp.net-core

Is their a way to get the name of the Area in a controller (programmatically)?

Following doesn't seem to work:

```
String currentArea = ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get it from `RouteData`:

```
var areaName = string.Empty;
object area = null;
if (RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("area", out area))
{
    areaName = area.ToString();
}
```